# Extracting a sequence as a decision variable from a matrix (PuLP)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, pulp

I am solving a sequencing problem `x[i][j]`, i.e. a binary matrix indicating that product `i` is followed by `j`. Each product is to be exactly scheduled once each, and `i` must be before `j` if `x[i][j] = 1`, which is enforced by auxiliary variable `p[i]`. This decision variable shows the index of the i-th element or row in the sequence. For the example below, `p[i]`, would be [0  2  1  4  5], read as entity/row 1 is in the 0th index in the sequence, entity or row 2 is at the 2nd index in the sequence, entity or row 3 at the 1st  index of the sequence and so on. I wrote this optimization in PuLP / Python.

So far, this problem works, but for some reason, I want to combine/integrate it into another problem. For this new problem, I need the exact sequence as in `x[i][j]` as a decision variable.

So, using constraints, I want to establish the produced sequence as another decision variable. Going by the example below (codeblock), this would be an array like [1 3 2 4 5] when counting from 1. This decision variable I want to call `o[i]`.
I could not figure out how to establish `o[i]` as a decision variable using only linear constraints on the given variables.

**example is below in the code block**

I have excluded my initial solution and costs function for privacy reasons!

```
# the decision variable is a succesion matrix of i by j, i.e. whether i is followed by j
    x = LpVariable.dicts("transition", (range(N), range(N)), 0, 1, cat='Binary')
    
    # example x[i][j], which is N by N
    # [0 0 1 0 0]
    # [0 0 0 1 0]
    # [0 1 0 0 0]
    # [0 0 0 0 1]
    # [0 0 0 0 0]
    #
    # read as (row) i is succeeded by (column) j
    # so, since the 1st column has no predecessor  (column sum 0) , it is the initial product
    # thus, starting in row 1, it can be observed that the sucessor is column 3, so product 3
    # so 1 -> 3, now do the same for row 3, 1 -> 3 -> 2
    # the order in this example is 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5
    
    
    
    # auxiliary variable to enforce a single starting point
    #u = LpVariable.dicts("position", range(N), 1, N)
    
    # axuiliary variable to maintain position integrity
    # p[i] variables (integer: position of entity i in the loop)
    p = LpVariable.dicts("position", range(N), lowBound=0, upBound=N-1, cat='Integer')
    

    prob.setObjective(costs)
    
    
    # constraint 1: each product has exactly one sucessor
    # we do not enforce this hard, since the last scheduled has no successor
    for i in range(N):
        prob += lpSum(x[i][j] for j in range(N)) <= 1

    # constraint 2: each product is preceded by exactly one other
    # we do not enforce this hard, since the first one does not have a predecessor
    for j in range(N):
        prob += lpSum(x[i][j] for i in range(N)) <= 1
        
        
    # constraint 3: the total number of movements is at max N-1
    # this means every product is selected once, except the start product
    prob += lpSum(x[i][j] for i in range(N) for j in range(N)) == N - 1
    
    
    
    # constraint 4: avoid circular dependencies, i.e. 1 -> 2 -> 1 is not allowed
    # this means a sequence cannot loop back to a previously visited point
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
                prob += x[i][j] + x[j][i] <= 1
                
                
             

    # constraint 7: the start product has no predecessor
    prob+= lpSum(x[i][zero_j] for i in range(N)) == 0
    
    # constraint 8: the start product must have a successor
    prob+= lpSum(x[zero_j][j] for j in range(N)) == 1
    
    # constraint 9: the upper bound for the costs is the baseline value
    # this baseline comes from warm_start
    prob += costs <= baseline
    
    # constraint 10: positional constraint
    # if i is in the sequence, its position must be smaller than j if j is after i
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
                prob += p[i] + 1 <= p[j] + M * (1-x[i][j])
                
        
                
    # constraint 11
    # the sum of assigned positions should be equal to the sum of range N
    # i.e. each position is present once
    prob += lpSum(p[i] for i in range(N)) == sum_n
```

Comment: Search for MTZ constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $i,j\in \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace$ and $o_i$ is an integer variable with domain $\lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace$ for each $i.$ You can add the constraints $$o_i + x_{i,j} - N(1-x_{i,j}) \le o_j \le o_i + x_{i,j} + N(1-x_{i,j})$$ for every index pair $i\neq j.$ If $x_{i,j}=1,$ this forces $o_j = o_i + 1.$ If $x_{i,j}=0,$ the corresponding constraints are nonbinding.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented is as follows.


for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        prob += o[i] + x[i][j] - N*(1-x[i][j] <= o[j] <= o[i] + x[i][j] + N*(1-x[i][j])

However, it produced the same results as p[i], i.e. did not generate the exact produced sequence in x[i][j]. 

In essence, what am I seeking, is a decision variable which orders elements over range(N), in this case integers, according to values in p[i].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it as follows

Created $z_{ij}$, shaped similarly to $x_{ij}$

```
# zij is auxaillary to determine oi
z = LpVariable.dicts("auxiliary", (range(N), range(N)), cat='Integer')
```

Then, fill with 1's such that the column index multiplied with the '1' equals the position $p$ of the $i$-th element. Also enforce binary

```
for i in range(N):
prob += lpSum(j*z[i][j] for j in range(N)) == p[i]

for j in range(N):
    prob += z[i][j] <= 1
    prob += z[i][j] >= 0
```

In addition, make sure no values are redundantly placed

```
for i in range(N):
    prob += lpSum(z[i][j] for j in range(N)) == 1  


for j in range(N):
    prob += lpSum(z[i][j] for i in range(N)) == 1
```

Then, the exact order can be deduced by taking the index of the row and multiply it with the 1.

```
for j in range(N):
prob += o[j] == lpSum(i*z[i][j] for i in range(N))
```